# Understanding traits in Kotlin

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, language-design, traits, kotlin

In [Kotlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_%28programming_language%29) we'll have possibility to create a "trait that may require a class being extended on the call side", like

```
 class Bar {}
 trait T1 : Bar {}
 class Foo : Bar, T1, T2, T3 {}
 class Wrong : T1, T2 //error: Wrong should extend Bar
```

I can't imagine any flow where I can apply this structure. Can anyone tell me why we need it?

Comment: I recommend we close this question, traits do not exist anymore and their semantics have changed significantly once renamed to interfaces to match Java 8 semantics.  This can be closed as irrelevant, now misleading for modern Kotlin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the main reason for this is to allow the trait to make use of methods and properties defined in the concrete class. Imagine that `Bar` had some basic method that other convenience methods could be built on top of... by having the trait require that it be used on subclasses of `Bar`, you could define methods in the trait that call that method. You could then provide those methods to many subclasses by giving them the trait.